# Why symfony does not recognize the route with placeholders

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following route in php

```
$collection->add('verify', new Route('/verify/{confirmation}', array(
   '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Verify:verify',
)));
```

And I want to generate a url with the confirmation parameter

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('verify', array('confirmation' => $user->   getConfirmation()));
```

and show it on a twig template

```
a href="{{ url('url') }}"
```

but I'm getting this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "url" as such route does not exist.") in Emails/registration.html.twig at line 5.
>   500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
>   1 linked Exception: RouteNotFoundException »

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you twig template change `a href="{{ url('url') }}"` to:

```
a href="{{ url('verify', {'confirmation': app.user.confirmation}) }}"
```

**or** `{'confirmation': confirmation}` and make sure to pass `confirmation` variable to template from controller.